# Scroll to top of grid

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have been researching this but nothing seems to work. I am using Ionic 5 and angular 8. I have a div, and in there is an ion-grid which shows my query results. At the bottom I have paging. My issue is that when you click to go to another page of results, angular sends a server side request for the next page and it successfully loads, but the page remains at the bottom of the page where the paging is. I want it to go back to the top of the list when the new page is loaded.
Further complicating this (I assume) is my toolbar and a "sticky" header row (ion-row) which I am thinking makes the page think that it is already scrolled to the top. I have tried scrollTo on both the window and the div in my angular code but it has no effect.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this by putting the entire div and grid into an ion-content tag, with scrollevents set to true. I then used @ViewChild to reference the content element and in my angular code I called this.content.scrollToTop

HTML:

```
<ion-content [scrollEvents]="true" #RecordList>
  <div>...</div>
</ion-content>
```

In angular:

```
import { IonContent} from '@ionic/angular';
export class MyPage implements OnInit  {
    @ViewChild('RecordList',{ static: false}) content: IonContent;
    ...
    scrollTop  {
       this.content.scrollToTop(1500);
    }
```

[This link assisted me](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-how-to-scroll-to-top-bottom-using-ion-content-scroll-events/)